# A parent record isn't added to a database after a child record has been added

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, relational-database

I'm trying to create a database containing a single self-referenced table "Categories" using Code First approach. Here is the definition of the Category POCO entity:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; private set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentCategoryId")]
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

and here is the definition of the DbContext subclass for the database:

```
public class CategoryContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public CategoryContext()
        : base("name=CategoriesEntities") { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(cat => cat.SubCategories).WithOptional(cat => cat.ParentCategory).HasForeignKey(cat => cat.ParentCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to fill the table:

```
using (var context = new CategoryContext())
{
    var child = new Category { Name = "child" };
    var parent = new Category { Name = "parent" };
    parent.SubCategories.Add(child);
    //child.ParentCategory = parent;
    context.Categories.Add(child);
    //context.Categories.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But the only record I see in a resulting table is the "child" record. But if I change `parent.SubCategories.Add(child)` line to `child.ParentCategory = parent` line, everything will work fine and the table will contain both records. Everything will be ok also if I change `context.Categories.Add(child)` to `context.Categories.Add(parent)`.

So, what am I doing wrong? Why isn't parent record added to the table along with it's child record? How can I achieve the desired behavior without making the substitutions listed above?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this behavior because you are only saying it to add chield

```
context.Categories.Add(child);
```

and if you look at your child object it has no association with you parent , but you parent have association with child (one way relationship) so when you do context.Categories.Add(child); EF has no clue about parent

So right way to do is to add parent object only

```
context.Categories.Add(parent);
```

Changed code should look something like

```
using (var context = new CategoryContext())
{
    var child = new Category { Name = "child" };
    var parent = new Category { Name = "parent" };
    parent.SubCategories.Add(child);
    context.Categories.Add(parent);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

}

If this had helped you don't forgot to mark it as answer :)

Comment: Oh, now I see. Category is a plain CLR (not EF) class, so EF can't trace whether some instance has been added to the child collection of the other instance. It's rather obvious :(